# How to get the standard deviation when summing down a category with multiple independent observations?

Tags: repeated-measures, standard-deviation, sample-size

I am not sure how to handle calculating the standard deviation in my situation.

Four researchers (i.e., R1, R2, R3, and R4) are taking independent measurements of the same variable—the time that a subjects talks in a conversation. Let's say there are 6 subjects. Each subject can be grouped into one of 2 roles: A or B.

The subjects are having a back-and-forth conversation, such that the measurements take the following form:

| Subject Speaking | Role | R1 Measurement (seconds) | R2 (seconds) | R3 (seconds) | R4 (seconds) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 12 | 13 | 12 | 14 |
| 3 | B | 56 | 52 | 51 | 55 |
| 5 | B | 30 | 33 | 32 | 34 |
| 2 | B | 27 | 24 | 28 | 27 |
| 1 | A | 167 | 164 | 152 | 165 |
| 6 | A | 13 | 17 | 17 | 18 |
| 3 | B | 83 | 78 | 82 | 85 |
| 4 | A | 63 | 68 | 61 | 52 |
| 1 | A | 26 | 18 | 26 | 38 |

If I want to get the average across researcher measurements for the amount of time that people from role A and B were speaking, what is the most appropriate way to get the standard deviation:

**Option 1)** Should I sum down each researcher's measurements within each role and then take the mean and standard deviation across researchers to get something like this:

| Role | R1 (s) | R2 (s) | R3 (s) | R4 (s) | Mean (s) | Stdev (s) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 281 | 280 | 268 | 287 | 279 | 7.95 |
| B | 196 | 187 | 193 | 201 | 194 | 5.85 |

**Option 2)** Or, should I get the variance across researchers for each time a subject speaks and then sum down each role, like follows:

| Subject | Role | R1 (s) | R2 (s) | R3 (s) | R4 (s) | Mean (s) | Variance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 12 | 13 | 12 | 14 | 12.75 | 0.92 |
| 3 | B | 56 | 52 | 51 | 55 | 53.5 | 5.67 |
| 5 | B | 30 | 33 | 32 | 34 | 32.25 | 2.91 |
| 2 | B | 27 | 24 | 28 | 27 | 26.5 | 3 |
| 1 | A | 167 | 164 | 152 | 165 | 162 | 46 |
| 6 | A | 13 | 17 | 17 | 18 | 16.25 | 4.91 |
| 3 | B | 83 | 78 | 82 | 85 | 82 | 8.67 |
| 4 | A | 63 | 68 | 61 | 52 | 61 | 44.67 |
| 1 | A | 26 | 18 | 26 | 38 | 27 | 68 |

| Role | Mean (s) | Stdev (s) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 279 | 4.99 |
| B | 194 | 2.96 |

Additionally, **does anything change if one of the researchers misses a measurement** and the sample sizes are different?